# find string in multiple files with sorted dated

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i have multiple text files in that store emp name and date time
ex. file  A.txt
test  2019-05-02:10:00:00  car   2019-01-05:02:05:00
file  B.txt test
2019-01-08:08:00:00
car   2019-06-05:11:00:00
now i want to grep string test from all files in directory with order by date that is in text file.output like file B.txt test 2019-01-08:08:00:00 file A.txt test  2019-05-02:10:00:00
file b.txt should list first because in that date of test string is 2019-01-08:08:00:00

Comment: Formatting is just a trash. Even opening the question text as raw doesn't help in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can use

```
ls -lt
```

For reverse

```
ls -ltr
```